# Weight in Graph Using Jung

Tags: jung

I use Jung to draw a graph and the inputs are in .net format (Building it with txt2pajek). I want to see weights on edges and in output.
Please help me out how to do that?
Thanks

The code and .net file format are:

```
    package pGraph;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Paint;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import org.apache.commons.collections15.FactoryUtils;
import org.apache.commons.collections15.Transformer;
import org.apache.commons.collections15.functors.MapTransformer;

import com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.server.Container;

import pGraph.JungExample2.MyRenderer;

import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.layout.FRLayout;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.DirectedSparseGraph;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.Graph;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.io.PajekNetReader;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.GraphZoomScrollPane;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.VisualizationViewer;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.control.DefaultModalGraphMouse;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.control.ModalGraphMouse;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.decorators.EdgeShape;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.decorators.ToStringLabeller;

/** 
 * A class that shows the minimal work necessary to load and visualize a graph.
 */
public class D1
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();

        PajekNetReader pnr = new PajekNetReader(FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(Object.class));
        Graph g = new DirectedSparseGraph();

        VisualizationViewer vv = new VisualizationViewer(new FRLayout(g));


        vv.getRenderContext().setVertexLabelTransformer(pnr.getVertexLabeller());

        vv.getRenderContext().setEdgeLabelTransformer(new ToStringLabeller());


        pnr.load("F:\\1c\\qq.net", g);            


        DefaultModalGraphMouse gm = new DefaultModalGraphMouse();
        vv.setGraphMouse(gm);      


        System.out.println(g.toString()); 
        final DefaultModalGraphMouse<String, Number> graphMouse = new DefaultModalGraphMouse<String, Number>();
        graphMouse.setMode(ModalGraphMouse.Mode.PICKING);
        vv.setGraphMouse(graphMouse);  

        final GraphZoomScrollPane panel = new GraphZoomScrollPane(vv);

        jf.getContentPane().add(vv) ;
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.pack();
        jf.setVisible(true);  
          }
}
```

*Vertices 5

1 "t"

2 "b"

3 "c"

4 "d"

5 "a"

*Arcs

1 2 0.2

3 4 0.9

5 4 0.86

Answer (score 0):

`PajekNetReader.getEdgeWeightTransformer()` will give you the edge weights from the `Pajek` file.

You'll then need to provide a simple Transformer that can turn your `Transformer<E, Number>` into a `Transformer<E, String>`, and pass that to `vv.getRenderContext().setEdgeLabelTransformer()`.  (Using `toStringLabeller` doesn't make much sense because the edge objects are not, themselves, the weights that you want.)

http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/io/PajekNetReader.html